# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.python.keras.api._v2.keras.losses' has no attribute 'softmax_cross_entropy'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, cross-entropy

I have an AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.python.keras.api._v2.keras.losses' has no attribute 'softmax_cross_entropy' error when using tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy. Could someone help me?

Comment: Hey, Could you post a code example describing how you got this error ?

Comment: Well, I think I should use this: tf.compat.v1.losses.softmax_cross_entropy

Answer (score 0):

The `tf.losses` now point to `tf.keras.losses`. You can get identical behavior by using
`tf.losses.categorical_crossentropy` with `from_logits` set to `True`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we encounter this error, especially when running on online binders like jupyter notebook. Instead of writing

```
tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy
```

try

```
loss = 'softmax_cross_entropy'
```

or either of the below

```
tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()
loss = 'categorical_crossentropy'
```

You may also want to use from_logits=True as an argument - which shall look like

```
tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
```

while keep metrics something like

```
metrics=['accuracy']
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()